# Python iteratively add integer to string in list

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, loops, nested

I'm new to Python (2.7) and am stuck with a nested list. I got a nested list where the primary list A has 25 sublists. Each of those sublists have 21333 values, organised as a list.

The aim is to append to each item in the sublist an integer which would be 1 for the first element and 21334 for the last element in the sublist. This should be done for all sublists. In the end I would convert the primary part of the sublist to a float (e.g. 0.02) and the second part to an integer (e.g. 2).

The following picture shows a first attempt with the word 'hello' appended. However, in the end I'd like to append integers instead of a string.

[image: First attempt and console output]

My code is [on GitHub](https://github.com/unibe-geodata-modelling/2018-dambreaks-flooded-houses/blob/master/scratch_branch2_V3.py).

Comment: Please add your complete code,expected input and output

Comment: I have a file (shp) with house locations, another shp with river-nodes (21333) and a .edg-file with waterdepths for each of the houses at 25 different timesteps. For beeing able to use the library 'networkx' I need to get a list with all timesteps (TS1 to TS25) and each sublists (TS1-25) containing waterdepth for each of the river-nodes. So far I was able to do it, but I realised it would be great to have the Node-ID (equivalent to the index of each of the 21333 different water depths in the sublist) added to the sublists in form of another list (e.g. node index 2 would for example 0.03 2).

Comment: We are very keen here for the code you wish to show readers to be in the question itself. Partly this is because we don't want readers to have to go fetch it when it could be shown on the same page, but mainly this is because we find external links are often deleted, and when that happens we generally have the administrative work of deleting the question (since the question is no longer understandable). Of course, this will take any good answers with it, and we'd rather not do that. With that in mind, would you edit your question?

Answer (score 0):

what you have is an array of shape (25, 21333) and you want an array (25, 21333, 2) with `[your value, index]` of types `float` and `int`. this should work:

```
x, y = your_array.shape  # 25, 21333
indices = np.tile(np.arange(1, y+1), (x, 1))
result = np.dstack((your_array, indices)).astype(float, int)
```